# Multidimensional and associative array correct syntax

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create an multidimensional and associative array. I'm tried a PHP-like syntax but it doesn't work. How to solve?

```
var var_s = ["books", "films"];
var_s["books"]["book1"] = "good";
var_s["books"]["book2"] = "bad";
var_s["films"]["films1"] = "bad";
var_s["films"]["films2"] = "bad";
```

Comment: You could use an object?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Creating_new_objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use objects:

```
var var_s = {"books":{}, "films": {}};
var_s["books"]["book1"] = "good";
-> {books: {book1: "good"}, films: {}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want object literal syntax:

```
var_s = {
    books: {
        book1: "good",
        book2: "bad"
    },
    films: {
        film1: "good",
        film2: "bad"
    }
}
```

Retrieving a value:

```
var myBook = var_s.books.book1
```

Setting:

```
var_s.books.book3 = "terrible"
```

I recommend reading [You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS) for a good crash course in JS basics. [Chapter 2 of Book 1](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/up%20&%20going/ch2.md) specifically covers objects and initialization,

Answer (score 0):

You could use objects,

```
var Book = {
   'bookOne': 'good',
   'bookTwo': 'bad' 
};

/** Output => good **/
console.log(Book.bookOne);
```

**Note:** If you need, you can put an array within the object.

**Reading Material**

[Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)